# Unable to locate vocabulary and policies tab in Azure BizTalk Rules Engine API

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps, biztalk-services

I had an Azure BizTalk Rules Engine API in my orchestration in Azure but I noticed that a couple of days ago the tabs for adding/editing vocabulary and policies disappeared and the name of the instance also get changed to some Guid like format.

Any idea what's going on here and how to recover the vocabulary and policies I created in my Azure BizTalk Rules Engine instance.

Comment: Maybe you should ask that on the Azure forums...

Comment: I did verify this creating a new RulesService and for me i see the blades loading.